# combining columns vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm an absolute beginner. I'm trying to combine columns vertically. I want to stack columns on top of each other in a way that data from column 1, 5 and 9 will all be in the same column. But I'm struggling to do that.

```
    columns_1_to_4 = df.iloc[0:9, 0:4]
    columns_5_to_8 = df.iloc[0:9, 4:8]
    columns_9_to_12 = df.iloc[0:9, 8:12]

    new_df = pd.concat([columns_1_to_4, columns_5_to_8, columns_9_to_12], axis=0).ffill(axis=1)
```

I tried `ffill(axis=1)` for all three blocks as well as `new_df` but I just couldn't move the data from the original column. I appreciate any help. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Can you give one example using an actual dataframe and required output dataframe?

Comment: "I tried ffill(axis=1) for all three blocks as well as new_df but I just couldn't move the data from the original column." - **specifically exactly what code** did you write for these attempts? **What happened** when you tried using that code, and **how is that different** from the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your columns have not the same names:

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L
0   0   1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
1  12  13  14  15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
2  24  25  26  27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
3  36  37  38  39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47
4  48  49  50  51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
5  60  61  62  63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71
6  72  73  74  75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83
7  84  85  86  87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95
8  96  97  98  99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107
```

So (A, B, C, D) is different from (E, F, G, H) and (I, J, K, L), so `pandas` can't stack your columns because the indexes are not aligned. A simple way is to use `numpy` to reshape your dataframe:

```
# .iloc[:9, :12] is not mandatory if it's your whole dataframe
data = df.iloc[:9, :12].values.reshape(-1, 4)
out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      A    B    C    D
0     0    1    2    3
1     4    5    6    7
2     8    9   10   11
3    12   13   14   15
4    16   17   18   19
5    20   21   22   23
6    24   25   26   27
7    28   29   30   31
8    32   33   34   35
9    36   37   38   39
10   40   41   42   43
11   44   45   46   47
12   48   49   50   51
13   52   53   54   55
14   56   57   58   59
15   60   61   62   63
16   64   65   66   67
17   68   69   70   71
18   72   73   74   75
19   76   77   78   79
20   80   81   82   83
21   84   85   86   87
22   88   89   90   91
23   92   93   94   95
24   96   97   98   99
25  100  101  102  103
26  104  105  106  107
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know I could do that. But I'm sorry, my explanation was unclear and this wasn't exactly what I wanted to do. Actually, the order of cells in each cell matters and I want to keep the three blocks intact. So if I take the data frame you provided as an example, I want 4 below 96, 8 below 100 and so on. I took your advice and tried to reindex and change the columns name but it didn't work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @timeless answer did what I wanted to achieve. I'm sorry for the confusion. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *@Corralien* answer, here is how you can fix your code/*mis-alignment* :

```
dfs = [columns_1_to_4, columns_5_to_8, columns_9_to_12]
# or maybe [df.iloc[:9, i:i+4] for i in range(0, 12, 4)] ?

new_cols = None # you can choose to set any cols you want

new_df = pd.concat(
    map(lambda df_: pd.DataFrame(
        df_.to_numpy(), columns=new_cols), dfs)
)
```

Comment: Ah this is what I wanted to do. Thanks very much!